# R: How to stop fuzzyjoin::interval_join from producing duplicates on the edges?

Tags: r, intervals, fuzzyjoin

Recently I had to join two dataframes based on their timestamps.
The left data contains a fixed timestamp and the right a range.
I got it mostly working as you can see in my MWE, but the system tends to produce duplicate results at the crossing point from one range to the next. I've tried all the options, nothing worked.

Is there a nice way to suppress the duplicate entry?
In this example it is the bold one, number 13.
Of course you can try to filter it, but that feels rather hacky.

```
left.data <- data.frame(
  Data.left = 1:20,
  Timestamp = seq(
    ISOdatetime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 55, 10),
    by = "5 min",
    length.out = 20
  )
)

right.data <- data.frame(
  Data.right = 1:10,
  PeriodStartTime = seq(
    ISOdatetime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 55, 10),
    by = "hour",
    length.out = 10
  ),
  PeriodEndTime = seq(
    ISOdatetime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 55, 10),
    by = "hour",
    length.out = 10
  )
)

result <- fuzzyjoin::interval_join(
    x = left.data,
    y = right.data,
    by = c(
      "Timestamp" = "PeriodStartTime",
      "Timestamp" = "PeriodEndTime"
    ),
    mode = "left"
  )
```

| Data.left | Timestamp | Data.right | PeriodStartTime | PeriodEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 2 | 2000-01-01 11:00:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 3 | 2000-01-01 11:05:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 4 | 2000-01-01 11:10:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 5 | 2000-01-01 11:15:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 11:20:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 7 | 2000-01-01 11:25:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 8 | 2000-01-01 11:30:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 9 | 2000-01-01 11:35:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 10 | 2000-01-01 11:40:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 11 | 2000-01-01 11:45:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 12 | 2000-01-01 11:50:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| 13 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 1 | 2000-01-01 10:55:10 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 |
| **13** | **2000-01-01 11:55:10** | **2** | **2000-01-01 11:55:10** | **2000-01-01 12:55:10** |
| 14 | 2000-01-01 12:00:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 15 | 2000-01-01 12:05:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 16 | 2000-01-01 12:10:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 17 | 2000-01-01 12:15:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 18 | 2000-01-01 12:20:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 19 | 2000-01-01 12:25:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |
| 20 | 2000-01-01 12:30:10 | 2 | 2000-01-01 11:55:10 | 2000-01-01 12:55:10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone will provide another answer with `interval_join`, but here is something to consider with `fuzzy_left_join`.

Your match function `match_fun` could be set to allow for equality for the lower bound of the range (greater or equal to), but be less than the upper bound.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(
  left.data,
  right.data,
  by = c(
    "Timestamp" = "PeriodStartTime",
    "Timestamp" = "PeriodEndTime"
  ),
  match_fun = c(`>=`, `<`)
)
```

This result would give you:

```
   Data.left           Timestamp Data.right     PeriodStartTime       PeriodEndTime
1          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
2          2 2000-01-01 11:00:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
3          3 2000-01-01 11:05:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
4          4 2000-01-01 11:10:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
5          5 2000-01-01 11:15:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
6          6 2000-01-01 11:20:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
7          7 2000-01-01 11:25:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
8          8 2000-01-01 11:30:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
9          9 2000-01-01 11:35:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
10        10 2000-01-01 11:40:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
11        11 2000-01-01 11:45:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
12        12 2000-01-01 11:50:10          1 2000-01-01 10:55:10 2000-01-01 11:55:10
13        13 2000-01-01 11:55:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
14        14 2000-01-01 12:00:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
15        15 2000-01-01 12:05:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
16        16 2000-01-01 12:10:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
17        17 2000-01-01 12:15:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
18        18 2000-01-01 12:20:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
19        19 2000-01-01 12:25:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
20        20 2000-01-01 12:30:10          2 2000-01-01 11:55:10 2000-01-01 12:55:10
```